# trying to implement ps command in c but getting strange errors

Tags: c, ubuntu, compiler-errors, ps

I am trying to implement ps command in C and I am getting a lot of strange errors because of this.

#### My code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/procfs.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int fdproc;
DIR *dirp;
struct dirent *DirEntry;
struct elf_prpsinfo pinfo;

/*
 * open the /proc directory for reading process statuses
 */
int main()
{
    if ((dirp = opendir("/proc")) == (DIR *)NULL)
    {
        perror("/proc");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * loop for each process in the system
     */
    while(DirEntry = readdir(dirp))
    {
        if (DirEntry->d_name[0] != '.')
        {
            strcpy(procbuf, "/proc/");
            strcat(procbuf, DirEntry->d_name);
        }
        if ((fdproc = open(procbuf, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        /*
         * get the ps status for the process
         */
        if (ioctl(fdproc, PIOCPSINFO, &pinfo) < 0)
        {
            close(fdproc);
            continue;
        }
        /* process the pinfo stuff here, see
           /usr/include/sys/procfs.h for details */
        close(fdproc);
    } 
}
```

I found this code on the Internet somewhere and after doing some of my stuff in this I am still getting some strange errors like:

```
‘PIOCPSINFO’ undeclared
‘procbuf’ undeclared
```

which I think is something pre-defined in Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: procbuf is C++, so you need to compile any code accessing it as C++. See for example:   http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-934.3/libio/procbuf.h

Comment: If you want to use c, define char *procbuf; then use calloc and realloc to dynamically allocate an array of size strlen(dirent->name)+1+6; , the nul byte and /proc/. You also got a bug in your strcat line swap DirEntry to dirent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your errors problem:
define char *procbuf
and then try to check whether /proc directory is mounted or not so that you have access or of pid name directories attributes.also read more about ioctl function's argument *requests* so that you come to know what ind of approach can take you further in this problem.